# Clojure: sequences, mapping and the "current number/index" issue

Tags: clojure

I process all files in a directory, say:

```
(map file-handler files)
```

The only parameter to **file-handler** is naturally a file object. I want to know inside the **file-handler** the current "index" of the **files** sequence. The only solution I can see so far is to create a counter in the lexical closure, visible inside **file-handler**, and increment it there on each step. Perfectly feasible but not quite clojurelike. Is there a pure functional way to manage it?

Comment: Very often in FP it turns out that you don't need an index even though you thought you did. If you do then as @noisesmith's said, the general principle is to pass the 'mutating' value through the recursion as one of the arguments, e.g. `fold` and `reduce`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

map takes 1 or more arguments

```
(map file-handler (range) files)
```

there is also a shortcut for this

```
(map-indexed file-handler files)
```

This will require updating file-handler to take 2 arguments, or making a wrapper function that takes the index and the file and calls file-handler on the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, **noisesmith**! Neglected the RTFM part, shame on me.

Comment: as a general principle, in functional programming you can take any stateful variable, and turn it into an immutable function argument that gets passed forward.